# How to stop running dag using airflow rest api

Tags: airflow

I have a running dag, Can I stop it using REST API ?

There is a method to delete a running dag:
[https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/delete_dag_run。](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/delete_dag_run%E3%80%82)

But There is not REST API how to stop a running dag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the running tasks to `failed` with [Set a state of task instances](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_set_task_instances_state) note that this will stop the task from running and set the task status to failed but it will not invoke the `on_failure_callable` if you set one on your tasks nor it will invoke the `on_kill` method of the operator (if there is one).

If you want the DAG to not schedule any more tasks you can set it to Pause with [Update a DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/patch_dag)